# How to fix: Error thrown mapping result set into return type

Tags: postgresql, jdbi

I am using JDBI 3 to run update query which might update multiple rows. I want to get updated rows from the resultset.

However, I'm getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Error thrown mapping result set into return type

1. Tried to add @SingleValue to return signature, but still stuck with the same issue.
2. Unable to use @SqlBatch as this is a single query and @SqlBatch requires list.

```java
  @SqlUpdate(
      "UPDATE task_sync SET "
          + " is_active = false, "
          + " version = version+1 "
          + " WHERE task_id IN (<taskIdList>) "
          + " AND barcode IN (<barcodeList>) "
          + " AND is_active = true ")
  @GetGeneratedKeys("id")
  List<Long> deactivateTaskSyncByTaskIdInAndBarcodeList(
      @BindList("taskIdList") List<Long> taskIdList,
      @BindList("barcodeList") Set<String> barcodeList,
      @Bind("lastUpdatedById") Long lastUpdatedById);
```

Query generated:

```sql
UPDATE task_sync SET  is_active = false,  version = version+1  WHERE task_id IN (26)  AND barcode IN ('8606850380_0', '8696930120_0', '6907922280_0', '4605723180_0', '2354050010_0', '5259987660_0', '6392185330_0'
)  AND is_active = true 
RETURNING "id"
```

I expect this to return a list of updated ids.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right track.

To make it work you need to tell Postgres that you want to return the id column of all affected rows. You can do this by a adding `RETURNING id;` to the end of your query. The code would look like this:

```
@SqlUpdate(
      "UPDATE task_sync SET "
          + " is_active = false, "
          + " version = version+1 "
          + " WHERE task_id IN (<taskIdList>) "
          + " AND barcode IN (<barcodeList>) "
          + " AND is_active = true RETURNING id;")
  @GetGeneratedKeys("id")
  List<Long> deactivateTaskSyncByTaskIdInAndBarcodeList(
      @BindList("taskIdList") List<Long> taskIdList,
      @BindList("barcodeList") Set<String> barcodeList,
      @Bind("lastUpdatedById") Long lastUpdatedById);
```

Notice that you can also return multiple columns (e.g.: `RETURNING id, version;`) or event the entire row (e.g: `RETURNING *;`).

Comment: RETURNING "id" is already added to the query generated before. 
Postgres JDBC connector throws: No results were returned by the query.